# What does BUGBUG mean in minwindef.h?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Found this in minwindef.h:

```
typedef WORD                ATOM;   //BUGBUG - might want to remove this from minwin
```

I know what an ATOM is ... but what is up with "BUGBUG?"  This is in the 8.1 SDK, specifically:

\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\minwindef.h

Comment: A Microsoft programmer happened to notice it and went "hmm, that shouldn't be there" but didn't have the time to chase it down.  It shouldn't, don't have the time either.  This is not important.

Comment: It's a comment. What the exact phrase means isn't relevant to anyone but the person who wrote it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a tag used to mark things that should be investigated in the future.

"BUG" is too ambiguous:  you might use the word "bug" for all sorts of things when writing comments or code.  But it's unlikely that you're going to use "bugbug" (no spaces) anywhere, so by convention some development teams use it to track bugs or (as is the case here) things that should be investigated later.  This way the team can easily grep for "BUGBUG" and find all of the marked lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's a suggestion that ATOM should be moved into `winuser.h` rather than its current location.